# How can I make cloud foundry read from specific .env file in react app?

Tags: reactjs, cloud-foundry, pcf

I have a react app and it has **.env.development**, **.env.test**, **.env.production** files. They have only **REACT_APP_PROFILE** variable set in each of them, and their values are set to **dev**, **test** and **prod** accordingly.

I deploy my app using `npm run build` command and push it to cloud foundry using `cf push` command, and print out **process.env.REACT_APP_PROFILE** and **process.env.NODE_ENV** variables on the screen.

I have only one space in vmw apps manager called **'dev'**. I want this space to read **.env.test** file, but it reads from **.env.production** file (probably because I ran `npm run build` command) .

[image]

My questions are:

1- How can I make the space **'dev'** in apps manager read from my **.env.development** or **.env.test** file?

2- Should I create a different space in apps manager for each environment? If yes, then can I define different **manifest.yml** files such as manifest-test.yml, manifest-prod.yml? I only have one **manifest.yml** file right now and its content is like the following:

```
---
applications:
  - name: myreactapp
    instances: 1
    memory: 64M
    path: build/
    timeout: 120
    routes:
      - route: myreactapp.apps.xxx.xxx
    buildpack: staticfile_buildpack
```

Answer (score 0):

> > How can I make the space 'dev' in apps manager read from my .env.development or .env.test file?

I don't think that this is specific to CF. It's just cause by the files you are pushing to CF.

> (probably because I ran npm run build command) .

That would be my thought as well. You are using `cf push` to deploy the output of that command. If the output is built using production mode, you're only going to see production until you change the build process to product something in debug mode.

> 2- Should I create a different space in apps manager for each environment? If yes, then can I define different manifest.yml files such as manifest-test.yml, manifest-prod.yml? I only have one manifest.yml file right now and its content is like the following:

It's entirely up to you and how you want to organize and control access to your applications. I think controlling access is typically what affects the design of spaces the most.

You can invite different developers to each space. If, for example, you have dev and prod in different spaces, then you can effectively limit access to prod. You can invite the whole team to dev, but perhaps only your SRE team to prod. If you put all of your apps in the same space, then you can't make that type of distinction.

At the same time, more spaces are more work to manage so if you don't need to make that type of access control distinction, it's probably easier to have fewer spaces.

Answer (score 0):

A specific env file is used according to script ([docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/)):

- **npm start**: .env.development.local, .env.local, .env.development, .env
- **npm run build**: .env.production.local, .env.local, .env.production,
  .env
- **npm test**: .env.test.local, .env.test, .env (note .env.local is
  missing)

That said, you can configure your script to pick any file you want when building the application.